# How can I run Chromecast and FireTV programs on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: chromecast

I have a program similar to Chromecast/FireTV and I want it to run on a Raspberry Pi. Essentially, I want to turn the Raspberry Pi into a TV box, but with my program installed. Is this possible?

Comment: Its in english now, sorry about that. thanks for the advise

Comment: most likely possible ... you are asking about running a program on a Linux computer

Comment: Something like that, but with my program there, like a tv box

Comment: what is `my program`?

Comment: `Is this possible?` what happens when you run the program you have?

Answer (score 0):

You can download android tv on your Raspberrypi.
Just follow the instructions here:
https://raspberrytips.com/android-tv-on-raspberry-pi/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/133486)